# Getting HTTPError on Ubuntu Server while it works on my Windows PC

Tags: python, ubuntu, discord.py

I created a Discord Bot in Python which I want to be online 24/7 so I uploaded it to my Server.

The Bot is fully working on my Windows PC where Im creating this Bot.
I have made a html wrapper to get newest forum link of a forum category.

If I start the Bot on Windows it works. I will get the link etc.

But If a start it on my Ubuntu Server I will get the following Error:

```
  Ignoring exception in command patchnotes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "launcher.py", line 67, in patchnotes
    newspage.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 840, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://board.asharu.com/index.php?board/2-news-game
```

I checked the installed python3 modules with: `apt-cache search -n ^python3` and also trying to import all the modules I need via the Python Shell without getting Error so I guess all modules I need are installed.

The thing is, that I can't explain, why Im getting this Error only on my Ubuntu Server.

Here is the Code I use:

```
# command Patchnotes
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def patchnotes(ctx, *arg):
    """
        Get's the newest Topic of the Category "News Game" from board.asharu.com
        and send the link to the newest Topic to the chat.
    """
    #try:
    newspage = requests.get('http://board.asharu.com/index.php?board/2-news-game')
    newspage.raise_for_status()
    #except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        #return await client.say(err)
    tree = html.fromstring(newspage.content)
    for link_element in tree.xpath('//li[contains(@class, "columnSubject")]//h3//a'):
        href = link_element.get('href')
        return await client.say(href)
```

the imports I use are:

```
import discord
import logging
from lxml import html
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
```

I also tried to set an UserAgent without success:

```
newspage = requests.get('http://board.asharu.com/index.php?board/2-news-game', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
newspage.raise_for_status()
```

I tried to remove the `newspage.raise_for_status()` and printed the decoded content and got:

```
</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator">&bull;</span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item"><span data-translate="performance_security_by">Performance &amp; security by</span> <a data-orig-proto="https" data-orig-ref="www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing?utm_source=error_footer" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>

  </p>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  window._cf_translation = {};


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I guess the Ubuntu Server get's blocked from Cloudflare even giving a User Agent as Header.

On my Windows I will get a much larger html code which I want.

Comment: Kinda hard to see what is wrong with the url if we can't see the url. :)

Comment: You need to investigate why the URL is returning 403 in the first place. Does it require a login? Blocked IP range? Server acting up?

Comment: Nothing. It's a forum (WBB4) and there is a category which containes Patchnotes. This Category can be seen by everyone (no login needed). And the same code works if im starting the Python3 script on my Windows PC. Only on Ubuntu server it isn't working. So the URL and the code must be right if it's even works on windows.

Comment: I guess the IP is not blocked because I can ping the Webserver successfully.

Comment: Can you ping the http://ip:port ?

Comment: Yea I can ping it. @kmcodes

Comment: It probably doesn't like you using the default Python user agent, try spoofing your user agent to something like Mozilla/5.0

Comment: @squaswin Yea I read something about that and tried to do that: `newspage = requests.get('CENSORED_LINK', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})` without success.. Still working for Windows, but not for the Server.

Comment: @Rloqvist i added the link if u can do more with it.

Comment: Try getting Python 3.6

Comment: Why Python3.6 ? I thing Cloudflare's Anti-Bot protection is blocking. So i installed `cloudflare-scrape` and changed my code to it, without success.. Still getting HTML Code of the Cloudflare Page.

Comment: One thing you might try is to configure your requests to include an SSLContext, because if the status is a *403.4 - SSL required*, this might help. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#protocol-versions